# Assets for my game aren't showing (auto-py-to-exe)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

world!
I have a problem with my game. I already converted it to exe using PyInstaller (via auto-py-to-exe) and assets don't load. Any ideas how to solve it?

Command:

```lua
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "D:\Programming\Softwares\Python\Projects\Bonk!\icon.ico" --add-data "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/panda3d-1.10.11.dist-info;panda3d-1.10.11.dist-info/" --add-data "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/panda3d;panda3d/" --add-data "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/direct;direct/" --add-data "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/ursina-4.1.1.dist-info;ursina-4.1.1.dist-info/" --add-data "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/ursina;ursina/" --paths "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/panda3d"  "D:\Programming\Softwares\Python\Projects\Bonk!\main.py"
```

Comment: I think you have to add each and every file to the --add-data flags not just directories thats why its suggested to use spec files when there are a lot of files to add, then you can add them programmatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the spec file when adding a lot of data files to a pyinstaller project so that I can add them each programmatically.

In your pyinstaller spec file at the top

```
import os
data_dirs = [
    "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/panda3d",
    "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/direct",
    "D:/Programming/Softwares/Python/Lib/site-packages/ursina-4.1.1.dist-info"
]
targets = [
    "panda3d/",
    "direct/",
    "ursina-4.1.1.dist-info/"
]

lst = []
for data_dir, target in zip(data_dirs,targets):
    for item in os.listdir(data_dir):
        item = os.path.join(data_dir, item)
        lst.append((item, target))

a = Analysis(
         ...
         datas=lst,
         ...
```

Assign the list of tuples to the datas argument in the Analysis object, and then run `pyinstaller path-to-specfile.spec`

Here is a link to an explanation in the PyInstaller Docs

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle